# conditionally add attributes with handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I just tried something like this

```
<a {{createLink input}}>
```

And the helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('createLink', function (input) {
    if (input === 'x')
        return 'target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com"';
    else {
        return 'href="/bar-foo"';
});
```

This doesn't seem to work, I got errors like this:

> Exception in Meteor UI: Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 'target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com"' is not a valid attribute name.

so I was wondering if I did something worg here?

Comment: 1. You seem to be missing a `}` in your helper. 2. Are you sure that this issue is with the Handlebars helper? Where is `setAttribute` being called?

Comment: Can you add a bit more of the template you are using that inside?

Comment: That `}` was a typo. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8yg5/1/) which works, however, when I past that code into my meteor project it doesn't anymore. Maybe meteor uses an older version of handlebars

Comment: It seems that meteor ships with [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md) which probablies works different

Comment: Just figured it out, in Spacebars the helper needs to return an object  like: `{target: '...', href='...'}`